# AWS Elasticsearch Auto-Tune feature shows Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

I just updated AWS Elasticsearch from version 5.6 to 6.8. And there is an [Auto-Tune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/auto-tune.html) feature tab appeared in the Console. But it looks like does not work and shows only "Error" in front of Auto-Tune and nothing else.
After enabling Auto-Tune it show as Enabled, but after page reloaded changes to Error status back.
Is any solutions to fix this or additional ways to get more detailed error message?

[image]

Comment: Which [instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-instance-types.html) are you using?

Comment: I'm using m4.large.elasticsearch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I did not find any solution, I raised an AWS support ticket and got the answer.
This issue appears when the ES cluster migrating from an Elastic Search version which did not support Auto-Tune to one that does (in my case 5.6 to 6.8).

As a solution, the AWS service team manually deployed Auto-Tune agent on cluster and it took about a day.
After that I can enable or disable Auto-Tune as well.

BTW, new domains creates already with Auto-Tune feature enabled, so in the case of a new cluster, you should not face it.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, and it occurs because I'm using an unsupported instance type.
T2 and T3 instance types do not support Auto-Tune.

> **T2**
>
> - The T2 instance types **do not support** encryption of data at rest, fine-grained access control, UltraWarm storage, cross-cluster search, or **Auto-Tune**.

> **T3**
>
> - The T3 instance types **do not support** UltraWarm storage or **Auto-Tune**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-instance-types.html

Comment: It can be a case, but I use m4.large.elasticsearch instance type, so it should be supported.